# Can I uniquely identify or pull a class or div by its title using css

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I have two links and they are sharing the same style (class and div). But the problem is that, I don't know where is the html being pulled from. So I want to give different styles for each link. So I want to know if is it possible to target a class or div using title only?

here is the gnerated html:

```
<div class="event_legend_container">
    <div style="border-color:" class="event_legend_item activechildcat">
        <div style="border-color:" class="event_legend_name">
            <a title="HR Calender" href="/using-joomla/human-resources/2012-10-17-10-31-30/month.calendar/2013/05/20/85">
                HR Calender
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
<div style="border-color:#d3d3d3" class="event_legend_item ">
    <div style="border-color:#d3d3d3" class="event_legend_name">
        <a title="All Categories ..." href="/using-joomla/human-resources/2012-10-17-10-31-30/month.calendar/2013/05/20/-">
            All Categories ...
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```
a[title*="HR Calender"]{
  color:red;
}
a[title*="All Categories"]{
  color:green;
}
```

Here is the full list: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 1):

You can target element attributes like so:

```
a[title="HR Calender"] {color:red;}
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/VwBCt/2/

It would be more scalable to do this with classes however - a year from now you'll hate that you have 90,000 different link selectors! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the first link is inside event_legend_container so you can use

```
.event_legend_name a {style here}
.event_legend_container .event_legend_name a {first link style here}
```

if you want to style using title only, you can use attribute selector of css

```
a[title="Title here"] {style here}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use jquery if loaded to add/remove classes and attributes